# arr[strcspn(arr, "\r\n")] = 0; - What does "\r" mean?

Tags: c

I have a question. I am learning C programming and while reading and storing user input into a char array I came across this code. Can someone explain to me what the `"\r"` mean?
Thank you

```
arr[strcspn(arr, "\r\n")] = 0;
```

Comment: [Escape sequences](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/escape)

Comment: Some systems use `\n` (newline) for text file line endings, some use `\r` (return) and some use both. What you see is a typical "catchall" solution after reading a line with `fgets`, which retains the line endings. It removes all permutations of line ending that might be present. Or none, so it is bullet proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\r` is ASCII character 13, called "CR" or "carriage return".

Unix traditionally used \n (ASCII character 10, LF, line feed) as the end of a line, but Windows traditionally uses \r followed by \n (note that a lot of Windows functions do convert it to just \n). So to detect both, you can check for both \r and \n.

Answer (score 0):

As [user253751](https://stackoverflow.com/users/106104/user253751) suggested it is the carriage return.

To give some more context, there are the most important escaped character sequences related to new line, spaces etc..

| Character | Effect |
| --- | --- |
| \n | newline |
| \r | carriage return |
| \t | horizontal tab |
| \v | vertical tab |

Hope it is helpful!